# Java example code for generating a ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am expecting the code below to throw a ConcurrentModificationException, but instead I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I am aware that a ConcurrentModificationException is not guaranteed as per [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) included below, but I am attempting to recreate a scenario that leads to *ConcurrentModificationException* in order to better understand the mechanism of concurrency errors.

From [ArrayList javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

```java
public class RaceConditions {

    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 1000;
    private static final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 10000;
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String... args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            final int fi = i;

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ELEMENTS; j++) {
                        list.add(0, fi);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
}
```

My question is what would I need to modify in the code above in order to get a guaranteed (or almost guaranteed) *ConcurrentModificationException*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the name, a `ConcurrentModificationException` does not only occur in multi-threaded applications. Instead it usually indicates a collection was modified while you were iterating or otherwise interacting with the collection. As a `RuntimeException`, it generally indicates a programming error. If you don't misuse the collections you're working with, you should never see a CME.

The easiest way to generate one is to call [`.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) from inside a for-each loop. This happens because the `Iterator` that the for-each loop is using is keeping track of where in the collection it is (e.g. for an `ArrayList` it's tracking the current index). If you modify the collection by calling `.remove()` the iterator's state is no longer consistent with the collection's state, and therefore the iterator will fail-fast by raising a CME *if* it's able to detect the inconsistency.

Here's an example:

1. Construct an `ArrayList` containing `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
2. Call `.iterator()` to get an `Iterator` of this list. Internally the `Iterator` will be pointed at index `0`.
3. Call `.next()` on the iterator, returning `1` and advancing the internal pointer to index `1`.
4. Call `.remove(0)` on the list, to remove the 0th element, `1`, from the list, and shift the remaining elements forward one. Our list is now `[2, 3, 4]`.
5. Call `.next()` on the iterator. Since it's internal state points to index `1` it would return `3`, skipping `2`, which would be a problem. If possible the iterator will detect this inconsistency and fail, rather than silently continue erroneously.

All the collections in `java.util` do extra work to detect these inconsistencies and raise CMEs when possible, and most other popular collections (like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki)'s) do so as well. But it's not possible to always detect these issues and so they can only promise a best-effort level of error-checking, which is why the Javadoc has to be somewhat vague.

Comment: In case of removal the solution is clear - using `Iterator.remove()` instead of `list.remove(element)`. Thanks for spelling it out! :)

Comment: Yes, but you cannot access that method with a for-each loop. Often you should actually avoid doing that, and instead explore alternatives like constructing a different data structure as you iterate, rather than mutating the initial one. Using [immutable collections](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) makes this a logical strategy.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you always an ConcurrentModificationException

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Test");
        list.add("Test");
        list.add("Test");
        list.add("Test");
        list.add("Test");

        for(String item : list) {
            list.remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This exception is thrown when ever you try to change a collection while you currently iterating over it.

Comment: It should be noted that `Iterator`s allow you to iterate over a collection and modify it by removing items

Comment: @Marcinek: Thank you! I now realize I made an incorrect assumption that the exception is caused by concurrent access from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding this exception. From [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection **while another thread is iterating over it**.

In your example, there is no iteration over the list so this exception can never be thrown.

Comment: This quote doesn't make clear, however, that it is also not permissible for a thread to modify the collection while *the same thread* is iterating it, as in @Marcinek's example. Were I editing that documentation, I would replace "another" with "any".

Answer (score 0):

This should help in generating the concurrentmodificationexception: Access element via iterator and also modifying list directly

```
List<String> data1 = new ArrayList();
        data1.add("A");
        data1.add("AB");
        data1.add("ABC");
        data1.add("ABCD");

        Iterator itr = data1.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            itr.next();
            System.out.println(itr.next());
            itr.remove();
            data1.add("E");
        }
```